# splashscreen not being responsive for kotlin android app (appears squished on larger screens)

Tags: android, user-interface

I made a simple splashscreen for an app. I found that on the Pixel 2, it looked proper, but on larger screens like the Pixel 4 XL, it looked a bit squished.
[image]
[image]

The image is 1280x1920 and that fits in the 1280x1920 resolution of the Pixel 2. But it doesn't fit on larger phones like the Pixel 4 XL (1440x3040). Is there a way to make the image responsive to all viewports or will I have to make duplicate splashscreens with different res to fit all viewports?

My splashscreen here is a PNG file and imported as an image asset. I couldn't get Photoshop to export it as a SVG without the colours being changed to something different in the export. I know SVGs are for vector assets which I think are more responsive than image assets.

Comment: You can use this library to create responsive UIs. https://github.com/intuit/sdp#:~:text=README.md-,SDP%20%2D%20a%20scalable%20size%20unit,sp%20size%20unit%20for%20texts.

Comment: i will check that out.

Comment: There's a new native splash screen support via SplashScreen Compat API, more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate